# Finding the Uptime of a server programatically

Tags: vb.net, windows-server-2000, uptime

Does anyone know of a way to programatically find the uptime of a server running Windows 2000? We have a service running on the machine written in VB.NET, that reports back to our server via a webservice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way is to use the performance counters from .NET e.g.

```
Dim pc As PerformanceCounter = New PerformanceCounter("System", "System Up Time")

pc.NextValue() ' This returns zero for a reason I don't know

' This call to NextValue gets the correct value
Dim ts As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(pc.NextValue())
```

So basically, the PerformanceCounter class will return the number of seconds the system has been up and from there you can do what you want.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. As a reference for other people here is the converted VB code I used:

Dim uptimeTs As New TimeSpan()

Dim pc As New PerformanceCounter("System", "System Up Time")  
pc.NextValue()  
uptimeTs = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(pc.NextValue())

Comment: Please excuse the formatting, I'm new to this site and am still getting used to getting newlines in comments

Answer (score 0):

If you have SNMP enabled, you can query the following OID: 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0. This will give you the system uptime. It is defined as "The time (in hundredths of a second) since the network management portion of the system was last re-initialized."